# Have you ever seen someone try to implement the MVP pattern with ASP.NET Web Forms?

Tags: design-patterns, mvp, webforms

> Have you ever seen someone try to
>   implement the MVP pattern with ASP.NET
>   Web Forms?

And if so, how did they do it?

---

I'm working with a code base that is more than 10 years old.
Before I arrived, somebody tried to implement the MVP pattern with ASP.NET Web Forms.

I'm just wondering if this is unique to my code base or if other people have seen the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at [ASP.NET WebForms MVP](http://webformsmvp.com/).

> The ASP.NET Web Forms MVP project is about bringing the love back to Web Forms through a renewed approach to using it - an approach that facilitates **separation of concerns** and **testability** whilst maintaining the **rapid development** that Web Forms was built to deliver.

Comment: +1: Interesting. Do you know when this "movement" began? It didn't reach my dark corner of the earth until very recently. // And as my question implies, I'm not yet convinced that there are merits to this approach; especially when compared to the genuine article known as ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: No, it just came to my attention recently.  Personally, I am focusing on ASP.NET MVC, and have no legacy Web Forms apps to maintain.  In your case, this might be a good compromise if completely converting your existing WebForms application to MVC ends up being too much of a hassle.